# Mutt: how to color the first message of the thread?

Tags: colors, mutt

How to color the first message of an email thread in mutt?

Answer (score 3):

You can match the first message from a thread with the following pattern, which matches messages with no references:

```
!~x .
```

So something like the following configuration:

```
color index brightyellow default "!~x ."
```

Got to the answer from [here](http://promberger.info/linux/2009/09/16/mutt-match-messages-that-started-a-thread-and-have-no-replies/): match messages that start a thread and have no replies.

Comment: @Ian corrected the answer with quotes.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it works. It colors the first messages of a thread, and also the every other message not threaded.

Comment: @Ian If you want to change color only for the first message in thread and not affect messages without threads, this matching pattern should do the trick `~(!~x .)`